# How to load a file with a JSON array per line in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

An existing script creates text files with an array of JSON objects per line, e.g.,

```
[{"foo":1,"bar":2},{"foo":3,"bar":4}]
[{"foo":5,"bar":6},{"foo":7,"bar":8},{"foo":9,"bar":0}]
…
```

I would like to load this data in Pig, exploding the arrays and processing each individual object.

I have looked at using the JsonLoader in Twitter’s [Elephant Bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird) to no avail. It doesn’t complain about the JSON, but I get “Successfully read 0 records” when running the following:

```
register '/tmp/elephant-bird/core/target/elephant-bird-core-4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar';
register '/tmp/elephant-bird/hadoop-compat/target/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar';
register '/tmp/elephant-bird/pig/target/elephant-bird-pig-4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar';
register '/usr/local/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar';

a = load '/path/to/file.json' using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad=true');
dump a;
```

I have also tried loading the file as normal, treating each line as a containing a single column chararray, and then trying to parse that as JSON, but I can’t find a pre-existing UDF which seems to do the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think a custom UDF is the best solution in this case. Don't be afraid of UDFs. You are selling yourself short if you don't use them. Pig really isn't intended to solve that low-level of problems and that's what UDFs are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Donald said, you should use a UDF here. Here in [Xplenty](http://www.xplenty.com) we wrote JsonStringToBag to complement ElephantBird's JsonStringToMap.